# Fix Sonar violation: This call to "remove()" may be a performance hot spot if the collection is large

Tags: java, list, arraylist, sonarqube, sonarlint

I'm having an ArrayList and I'm removing elemts via arrayList.remove().

```
List<FooListener> listeners = new ArrayList ();

public void removeListener(FooListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener); // critical sonar warning
}
```

Sonar displays it as critical issue since it might has a performance impact:

**This call to "remove()" may be a performance hot spot if the collection is large.**

How should this be fixed?

Also I can only "Confirm" this issue in SonarQube and not just set it to something like "Won't Fix". How can it be ignored in irrelevant cases?

Comment: look at different types of List if performance is of concern - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java

Comment: I'd emphasize @ArunPJohny's comment *if performance is a concern*.

Comment: "How should this be fixed?" Is `removeIf` an option? Can you show the code?

Comment: Oh, I really wouldn't worry about the warning in that case. I really doubt you'll have a "large" number of listeners.

Comment: For listeners you might want to use a `Set` then. Its `remove()` method should not trigger the warning (see my edited answer).

Comment: You can use the `SuppressWarnings` annotations like `@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S00112")` where `squid:S00112` is a rule id

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself how "large" can *your* collections be. Don't try to micro-optimize too early, it probably isn't worth it.

`ArrayList` are good on many aspects (random access, memory footprint, ...) but not removing. `LinkedList` are good for removing (only when using an `Iterator` though, as noted by @AndyTurner) but not for random access, etc. Choose the appropriate one for *your* use case.

EDIT: If you're using an `ArrayList` to hold your listeners, you might want to use a `Set` instead, which `remove()` method should not trigger the "critical warning".

Comment: I mostly wouldn't want to actually fix it but sonarqube won't let me ignore the issue/set it to won't fix.

Comment: @Liso, that's interesting because the message says "*may be ... if*" ... but shows it as a "critical" issue?

Comment: yes, it displays it as critical and unlike other issues I'm not able to resolve it as fixed/won't fix or false positive.

Comment: "LinkedList are good for removing" it's only good for removing via an Iterator or with `removeIf`. Repeated calls to `List.remove(int)` are inefficient because each one has to walk the list to find that element.

Comment: @AndyTurner true, I edited to make it clearer.